# PHP opendir() authorization problem using Windows authentication on IIS

Tags: php, windows, iis, windows-authentication, opendir

I have a site on IIS with Windows authentication enabled and I'm trying to access a directory using opendir() function.

once authenticated with a domain user with rights for the directory opendir() returns me `Warning: opendir(\\myserver\myshare\mydirectory): Access is denied. (code: 5).`

the thing I can't understand is that if on IIS on that site I set the **Physical path:** > **Connect as...** setting to the **specific user** instead of **application user** it works

I noticed that get_current_user() returns me **Myuser** using **application user** and **myuser** using **application user**.

why can't I access the directory?

Comment: You might need to add the inbuilt iis_user account and grant access to the folder using Windows security options.

Comment: on the server that hosts the network share? why can't I use the domain user?

Comment: Because you are using PHP, where I don't think it supports Windows account impersonation. The setting "application user" requires impersonation/delegation to work behind the scene (which is usually supported by Microsoft technologies like ASP.NET).

Comment: so there's no way to manage files on PHP via Windows authentication on IIS? I have to set a specific user with rights to the folder and then manage the authorizations upstream?

Comment: the PHP service runs under a specific user and you need to grant that user access to the folder.

Comment: is there a way to run the service under the Windows authenticated user?